# New Section going above Previous Section

Tags: html, css

Trying to understand why my element seems to be placed on top of the previous section (right under the nav bar) instead of underneath it all as a new section. I'm trying to understand more about positioning in CSS so that may be what it is or simply an error in my HTML (but I can't seem to find it). I'm hoping someone can take a look real quick as to why that is.

Example:

Header Image

Nav Bar

(Quote that is misplaced is here instead of the bottom)

Section

New Section
(Where I want the quote to be)

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/resets-copy.css"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/waypoints.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/waypoints.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <title>Drifting</title>

</head>

<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
                <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay="0s">
                <h1>drifting</h1>
                </section>
                    <!-- <section class="os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".1s">
                <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
                </section> -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <header id="myHeader">
        <div class="logo" id="myMenu">
        drifting in the fall
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">home</a>
            <a href="#">about</a>
            <a href="#">journal</a>
            <a href="#">contact</a>
        </div>
    </header>

    <br>

<div class="container">
        <div class="left-side">
            <div class="info-container">
            <h1>text title<br>
            </h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id, nemo quo rem, unde deleniti natus eligendi a temporibus mollitia vero tempora voluptatem adipisci Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam nihil omnis, repudiandae explicabo natus nam earum quidem vero libero beatae rem iste quisquam. Cumque tempore magni officia, ipsa veritatis voluptate. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio doloremque modi natus sapiente, sed assumenda fuga esse, voluptates unde, dolorem vero dolore, quibusdam ex a placeat ducimus amet iusto numquam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex consequuntur suscipit enim! Debitis, ad, nam. Quisquam ullam facilis, tempore nisi nemo enim provident, ab dicta iusto animi obcaecati incidunt sapiente. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur corporis aperiam voluptas excepturi laborum nobis, nam ipsa aliquid commodi voluptatum illum, temporibus, beatae enim et totam. Enim similique officiis voluptates. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita aut amet saepe, repellat beatae! Illum natus autem obcaecati a, corporis vero, itaque ratione enim dolore aut ducimus quod, qui ut.
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
                <img src="IMG/GP1.jpg">
        </div>
</div>

<section>
    <div>
        <h2>A creative man is motivated 
by the desire to achieve, not by the desire 
to beat others - Ayn Rand
        </h2>
    </div>
</section>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Crimson+Text:400,400i,600,600i,700,700i|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700');
@import "resets.css";

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url('https://image.ibb.co/bF7T1L/site.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

.intro .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.content h1 {
    font-family: 'Crimson';
    color: white;
    font-size: 600%;
    font-style: italic;
}

/*.btn {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: 'Crimson';
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 2px solid white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: lightblue;
    border: 2px solid lightblue;
}*/

header {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    /*background: lightblue;*/
}

header .logo {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    padding-left: 13px;
}

header .menu {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;

}

header .menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: inherit; 
    padding-right: 12px;
}


header:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Crimson';
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 3%;
}

#myHeader {
    background: white;

}

.grand-prix {
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.gp-image {
    display: inline-block;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .left-side {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.container .right-side {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.container .right-side img {
    width: 70%;
}

.info-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 450px;
    left: 150px;
}

.info-container h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-style: italic;
    left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 25px;
}

.right-side img {
    position: relative;
    top: 290px;
    left: 130px;
}

.bottom h2 {
    color: grey;
}
```

Comment: You should try to use bootstrap 4  in your code. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/ . Bootstrap navbars are easy to use and automatically fit with your browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, you got two main problems:

1) Remove the `float: left` from `.container .left-side` in your CSS. You don't need it since that container is already to the left. This is also what appears to be causing the quote to jump to the top.

2) In `.info-container` you need to drastically lower the `top: 450px;` to something like `top: 10px` so that the text from the `.left-side` container isn't overlapping the quote that you want at the bottom of the page.

So for those two it should look like this:

```
.container .left-side {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.info-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Hey Christian, thanks so much for your feedback! Doing that put the quote under the paragraph but not under the entire section (it's still within the section). I'm going to look into it more!